# JSON-LD: Using data:post.body in Blogger template

Tags: templates, blogger, json-ld

I would like to use the post content in JSON-LD in my Blogger template.

I have the following JSON-LD code so far, which is errorfree, at least when I use the tool https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool:

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "BlogPosting",
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Billy Bathgate"
  },
  "image": {
    "@type": "ImageObject",
    "thumbnail": "thumbnail",
    "height": "100px",
    "url": "<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>",
    "width": "100px"
  },
  "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "My Blogspot Blog",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
     "url": "https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-G8FrqwN9Wl4/WD2Xz7xBKII/AAAAAAAAAD0/mjrZlZrDy1daudafdegai3LKxxVfaACPcB/s320/dfare-adfte-SaP-de-90dpi.png",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 53
    }
  },
  "keywords": "<data:post.labels/>",
  "headline": "<data:view.title/>",
  "dateModified": "<data:post.lastUpdatedISO8601/>",
  "datePublished": "<data:post.timestampISO8601/>",
  "description": "<data:post.longSnippet/>",
  "mainEntityOfPage": "<data:blog.homepageUrl/>"
}
```

So, how would I add the post content to JSON-LD? I've looked at http://jsonld.com/blog-post/, but

```
"articleBody":"<data:post.body/>"
```

will not be accepted.

Comment: In the new themes released by Blogger (Refer to https://blogger.googleblog.com/2017/03/share-your-unique-style-with-new.html ), they have included a tag for automatically generating the JSON-LD data of a post. The tag is `<b:include data='post' name='postMetadataJSON'/>` and only works inside the Blog widget. It contains the basic data but doesn't contain the articleBody attribute.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `<data:post.body.jsEscaped/>` or `<data:post.body.jsonEscaped/>` - similar to `.cssEscaped` which was a new find for me with the new templates. Lucky guess, but that's we're left to rely on without proper documentation for Blogger templating.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass validation by using `"articleBody":"<data:post.body.jsonEscaped/>"` but im not using it since its too long. i also found documentation on [Make Valid Blog Posting ldJson on Blogger](https://bloggerbook.blakbin.com/2018/10/make-valid-ld-json-for-every-blogger.html)