# Using a variable in a Blogger JSON-LD template

Tags: javascript, blogger, json-ld

I'm refering to the question [JSON-LD: Using data:post.body in Blogger template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41696276/json-ld-using-datapost-body-in-blogger-template).

Surprisingly, `<data:post.body>` can be used in the meantime. But now I have a new problem: How to eliminate tags, linefeeds and special characters and replace characters like `'` and `"`?

I found something in the kind of the following instead of directly write JSON-LD code, but it does not work:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var thisDdoesNotWork = removeHtmlTags_And_ChangeSomeCharacters("<data:post.body/>");
  var el = document.createElement('script');
  el.type = 'application/ld+json';
  el.text = JSON.stringify({
    "v1":"thisWorks",
    "v2":"<data:post.thisWorksToo/>",
    "v3":thisDdoesNotWork});
  document.querySelector('head').appendChild(el);
```

Someone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly render the content somewhere in the HTML via

```
<div class='post-body'>
    <data:post.body/>
</div>
```

Then, change your code as follows -

```
el.text = JSON.stringify({
"v1":"thisWorks",
"v2":"<data:post.thisWorksToo/>",
"v3":document.querySelector('.post-body').textContent});
```

You can also use `innerText` property (Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427621/innertext-vs-innerhtml-vs-label-vs-text-vs-textcontent-vs-outertext) to know the difference between `innerText` and `textContent`)